# PWABuilder iOS WebView 16.4 Web Push Not Working

Tags: ios, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, web-push

I have a PWA application which iOS now supports web push as of 16.4. If I save the PWA app from the browser to my home screen then the logic to check the current notification permission and prompt the user to allow notifications works just fine as you would expect!

However, if I bundle my PWA up using PWABuilder and deploy it to testflight for some internal testing, the same PWA will throw an exception: Can't find variable: Notification

Also good to mention PWABuilder is working just fine in Google Play Store as expected!

So originally I remembered that XCode did not default the release to 16.4 but like 13.0 so I gave them the benefit of the doubt that they run an older version of WebView in this scenario. However, I did to the best of my none Apple knowledge address this in XCode and tried again with the same error exception.

Is this really expected behavior, does this scenario work for someone else, or does anyone have ideas on how to address this problem? Thanks in advance!

I tried troubleshooting the problem by proving out it works from a browser download and fails in the app store app. I tried different release versions in XCode with no luck. I also reached out to apple feedback channel as I feel it's a bug but hopefully I am wrong.

**Update (+1 day)**

Safari downloaded PWA shows navigator.appVersion of "16.5.2" while app store version shows "15.0"...going to look into why this is the case, guessing it's on my end at this point but any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: same problem, got a hint from your update, thanks. maybe we should find a way how to configure appVersion to >16.4

Comment: Nope, they just don't support it in WKWebView. You will have to use Firebase or something else in the meantime.